# Delete Specific Items from NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I'm trying to perform the relatively simple task of deleting the items in an NSMutableArray that fit a certain criteria.

In this particular case, I'd like to delete the items where all of the following are true:

- city: Seattle
- state: WA
- timestamp: more than 60 seconds old

**An NSLog of my array looks like this:**

```
array = (
            {
            city = "Seattle";
            state = "WA";
            timestamp = 1432844384;
        },
            {
            city = "Dallas";
            state ="TX";
            timestamp = 1432844415;
        },
        {
            city = "Seattle";
            state = "WA";
            timestamp = 1432845329;
        }
    )
```

I've tried using NSPredicate to filter the array, but I think that may be overcomplicating things. Any recommendations would be great! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You could get the indexes of such elements by using `indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:` ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:))

```
NSIndexSet *indexes = [array indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    // check if obj is matching all your criteria
}
```

Then remove the items using `removeObjectsAtIndexes:` ([see docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectsAtIndexes:))

```
[array removeObjectsAtIndexes:indexes];
```

Answer (score 1):

No, filtering out the items to delete and then deleting them is the right way. It iw not complicated, because obviously getting the specified items is filtering with a predicate + deleting them is deleting them. How could a solution be less complicated?

Maybe it is easier to you, to filter out the items not to delete. Simply add a `NOT` to your predicate.

Answer (score 0):

Here your timestamp is unique every time. So you have delete data base on timestamp.

First you have to get index of that timestamp from that array.

```
NSInteger index = [[array valueForKey:@"timestamp"] indexOfObject:timestamp];
```

After getting this index of array you have to delete data from that index.

```
[array removeObjectAtIndex:index];
```

Comment: The question was about removing all items matching 3 different requirements - how is looking for one single timestamp helping there?

Comment: If you can delete using timestamp then why should you have to check 3 requirements?